# java.util.concurrent bounded resuable resource implementation

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm trying to code following requirements with lockfree in most-used-code-path that is to get a resource from pool.

1. Same resource should be used n (`maxUsageCount`) number of times and then
   destroyed and create a new one.
2. If there is an error with a resource, it should be marked `stale` by
   client. Staled resource should be destroyed and not handed out to 
   the clients, a new resource should be created.
3. Resource must be closed after `maxUsageCount` otherwise its leak.

Resource is threadsafe.

```
public class ReusableResource<T extends ResourceProxy> {

    public static interface Factory<T extends ResourceProxy> {
        T create();
    }

    private final int maxUsageCount;
    private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>> resources;
    private final Object lock;
    private final ReusableResource.Factory<T> factory;

    public ReusableResource(int maxUsageCount,
            ReusableResource.Factory<T> factory) {
        if (maxUsageCount < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("maxUsageCount " + maxUsageCount);
        if (factory == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("factory " + factory);

        this.maxUsageCount = maxUsageCount;
        resources = new AtomicReference<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>>(
                new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>());
        lock = new Object();
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public T get() {
        final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> tmpq = resources.get(); // load once

        T res = tmpq.poll();

        if (res == null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                res = tmpq.poll(); // double check
                // empty queue, first time or none left
                if (res == null) {
                    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> newq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>(
                            Collections.nCopies(maxUsageCount, factory.create()));
                    // checkout the one we are returning
                    res = newq.poll();
                    // overwrite q object, do not modify existing
                    this.resources.set(newq);
                    // no stale check on newly created instance
                    return res; // <<- exit,
                }
            }
        }

        if (res.isStaled()) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                // once staled its going to remain staled
                // no need for double check

                // call destroy on all remaining elements
                // so that it can actually be closed
                // this might cause more destroy then checkouts
                // and so destroy must be idempotent
                res.destroy();

                while ((res = tmpq.poll()) != null)
                    res.destroy();

                // create new resources queue, same as first time
                final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> newq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T>(
                        Collections.nCopies(maxUsageCount, factory.create()));
                // checkout the one we are returning
                res = newq.poll();
                // overwrite q object, do not modify existing
                this.resources.set(newq);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

ResourceProxy.java

```
public abstract class ResourceProxy implements Disposable {
    private final AtomicInteger usageCount;
    private volatile boolean staled;

    public ResourceProxy(int maxUsageCount) {
        if (maxUsageCount < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.usageCount = new AtomicInteger(maxUsageCount);
        this.staled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        if (usageCount.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
            closeResource();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setStaled() {
        this.staled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStaled() {
        return staled;
    }

    abstract protected void closeResource();

}
```

Example usage:

```
public class QueueConnectionProxy extends ResourceProxy implements
        QueueConnection {

    public static class Factory implements
            ReusableResource.Factory<QueueConnectionProxy> {
        private final int maxUsageCount;

        public Factory(int maxUsageCount) {
            if (maxUsageCount < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            this.maxUsageCount = maxUsageCount;
        }

        @Override
        public QueueConnectionProxy create() {
            return new QueueConnectionProxy(maxUsageCount);
        }
    }

    private final QueueConnection delegate;

    public QueueConnectionProxy(int maxUsageCount) {
        super(maxUsageCount);
        delegate = createDelegate();
    }

    private QueueConnection createDelegate() {
        // create QueueConnection
        return createdQueueConnection
    }

    @Override
    protected void closeResource() {
        try {
            if (delegate != null) delegate.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: log JMSException
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws JMSException {
        destroy();
    }

    // other delegate methods
    //

}
```

To create an instance of `ReusableResource`:

```
ReusableResource<QueueConnectionProxy> reuse = 
  new ReusableResource<QueueConnectionProxy>(
    10, new QueueConnectionProxy.Factory(10));
```

Client code:

```
QueueConnection qc = null;
try {
    qc = reuse.get();
} finally {
    try { qc.close(); }
    catch (JMSException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Code Review.

You have posted an very good quality post and that's why it takes so long to get an answer.

I have 2 minor remarks to make.

### First :

```
if (maxUsageCount < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

You do this check 3 times, I have no problem with that.
But what if your maxUsageCount is 0 ? 
I think this is an unwanted situation so better to do :

```
if (maxUsageCount <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

### Second :

The clientCode :

```
QueueConnection qc = null;
try {
     qc = reuse.get();
} finally {
    try { qc.close(); }
    catch (JMSException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

You do not check if qc is null, what is possible when you get an exception.
You have 2 options for this.

```
QueueConnection qc = null;
try {
     qc = reuse.get();
} finally {
    if (qc!=null) {
        try { qc.close(); }
        catch (JMSException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

**edit :**
This last one is wrong cause `QueueConnection` doesn't implement `AutoClosable`.

<s>Or from java 7 you can use try-with-resource</s>
When you extend `QueueConnection` and implement the `AutoClosable` you can do the following :

```
try (QueueConnectionAutoClosable qc = reuse.get()) {
    //custom code what you need to do.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general it *looks* good, now going through the code to also see if it actually is good.

#### 1. Exception messages

Your exception messages should be made clearer, an example of them is at the constructor of `ReusableResource`. If `maxUsageCount < 0` or `factory == null`, we get echoed the value of the variable back, but no indication whatsoever to what is actually wrong with it. It would be good to see it included. Also `maxUsageCount == 0` is most likely not wanted, is it? Lastly on this point, I would prefer `this.factory = Objects.requireNonNull(factory)` **if** you only use `factory` once, as the case is here. If it would be used multiple times, then there should be a simple `Objects.requireNonNull(factory)` check at the top of the method, to ensure the check only runs once.

#### 2. Initialize objects as early as possible.

You are initializing both `resources` and `lock` in the constructor, and not at declaration time, which looks suspicious. They do not depend on either `maxUsageCount` or `factory` passed into the constructor. Hence I see no reason to initialize them late. This prevents duplicate code when adding more constructors.
This also holds for `delegate` in `QueueConnectionProxy`.

#### 3. Try to use more meaningful variable names.

As a reader of the code, it is very hard to get the meaning of `tmpq` in `ReusableResource.get()`, after some thinking (which is a precious resource) I realised it was meant to be temporary queue, just name it `tempQueue` then.

#### 4. Consider factory methods.

The lines:

```
ReusableResource<QueueConnectionProxy> reuse = 
  new ReusableResource<QueueConnectionProxy>(
    10, new QueueConnectionProxy.Factory(10));
```

are simply too long. Your code would benefit from giving `ReusableResource` a static method that creates a new `ReusableResource`, more over it *seems* that the `10` parameter is specified two times there, though I might be wrong. In either case, your static method would be called as `ReusableResource.newInstance(10)` or `ReusableResource.newInstance(10, 10)`. This also hides the specification of the type parameter multiple times.

#### 5. Use try-with-resources if possible

I do not know all places where try-with-resources is possible in your code after a brief look, but the following seems a good candidate:

```
QueueConnection qc = null;
try {
    qc = reuse.get();
} finally {
    try { qc.close(); }
    catch (JMSException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Which would become:

```
try (QueueConnection qc = reuse.get()) {
    //use
}
```

For this you might need to implement `AutoClosable` yourself, I cannot tell if that is possible.

That leads to the end of the review, unfortunately I am only able to touch the basic concepts and not the low level concurrency stuff as I consider myself not experienced enough to give advice upon that yet.